# How to access to instance variable(which is not defined in "__init__") in class in python?

Tags: python, instance-variables

I should access the variable in a method in the class.

Because I did some data cutting in the method, I need the data of which data cutting is already done.

But I can access an instance variable that is only defined in the "__init__" method.

I give an example because of making clear my question. Let's see the below code.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def t(self,c,d):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

FirstTest = test(3,4)
print(FirstTest.a)

SecondTest = test(3,4)
print(SecondTest.t(30,40).c)
```

I need "c" and "d", but I can not access of these. I only access to "a" and "b"
If I try to access "c" and "d", below error is coming up.

```
---> 13 print(SecondTest.t(30,40).c)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Is there no code I can access the instance variable which is not defined in "__init__"?

Comment: The t method doesn't return the instance, it returns None. You can access c and d if you do so on that actual instance _after_ calling that method.

Comment: The `t` method doesn't return anything, so it's meaningless to try to access the `c` attribute of it.  You need to do the method call as a separate statement from printing the attribute.

Comment: The standard convention in Python is to capitalize the *class* names, and use all lowercase for the variables referring to instances. `class Test: ...`, `first_test = Test(3, 4)`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `t()` method doesn't return the instance. You can access the attribute after calling the method by referring to the variable.

```
SecondTest.t(30, 40)
print(SecondTest.c)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `t()` returns nothing, or `None`. You can do as the previous answer suggests and `return self`, but this isn't normally a good idea. If you just want c, use:

```
SecondTest = test(3,4)
SecondTest.t(30,40)
print(SecondTest.c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from `t()`, so `None` is returned. If you want to chain method calls with an attribute access, you'll need to `return self` so that the return value of `t` is the object whose attribute you want to access (though, as [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) points out, mutating an instance *and* returning it can be hard to reason about, so be sure that you want to support this kind of interface before actually implementing it):

```
def t(self,c,d):
    self.c = c
    self.d = d
    return self
```

This outputs:

```py
3
30
```

Comment: But note that the convention in Python is for methods that mutate the instance to return None, rather than this kind of "fluent interface".

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Thanks for the comment but it's not suitable in my case because I should return another value for 'curve_fit'